# PhantomJS - 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I'm trying to change the value of a input with PHP webdriver and PhantomJS. When I run a simple

```
$driver->executeScript("document.getElementById('changeme').value='".$newvalue."' ;", array());
```

I get the following error

> *Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because unsafe-eval is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive*

I've got the following command line options set

```
--ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks! Corrected. Take a look and if not correct point me to right direction